# Handle nested conditions in Spring Reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have 3 checks which I need to make in an incremental way.

```
Mono<Boolean> isRegistered(Student std);
Mono<Boolean> isEligible(Student std);
Mono<Boolean> isAvailable(Student std);
```

Each method performs a check inside and returns `true / false`

I want a logic that will stop the flow and throw error if any of the checks return `false`
something like this:

```
Mono<Boolean> checkAll(Student std) {
return isRegistered(std) && isEligible(std) && isAvailable(std);
}
```

I tried with `Mono.zip()` but it allows only 2 params, also it does not allow to run 2nd condition only after 1st condition is true.

I also tried with `Mono.defer().then()` like this

```
return Mono.defer(() -> 

         isRegistered(std))
        .then(Mono.defer(() -> isEligible(std))
        .then(Mono.defer(() ->isAvailable(std));
```

but the problem is it returns `true` if any one of the condition is `true`

I want to call the 2nd method only if first method is `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive approach is to evaluate conditions sequentially using `flatMap` and complete sequence (return `Mono.empty`) in case some condition is `false`.

```
condition1()
    .flatMap(res -> {
        if (!res) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        return condition2();
    })
    .flatMap(res -> {
        if (!res) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        return condition3();
    })
    .flatMap(res -> {
        if (!res) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        return action(); // if all conditions true
    })
    .switchIfEmpty(otherAction()); // else
```

You can also use `Mono.zip` that supports up to 8 publishers or you can pass `Iterable` if you need more. `zip` subscribes eagerly (to all publishers) and wait until all conditions are evaluated. We can overcome the second restriction by using the fact that empty completion of any source will cause other sources to be cancelled and the resulting `Mono` to immediately complete.

```
Mono.zip(emptyIfFalse(condition1()), emptyIfFalse(condition2()), emptyIfFalse(condition3()))
    .flatMap(__ -> action()) // all conditions TRUE
    .switchIfEmpty(otherAction()); // some condition FALSE

private Mono<Boolean> emptyIfFalse(Mono<Boolean> condition) {
    return condition
            .filter(res -> res);
}
```

In this case all conditions are still evaluated in parallel (that could be an advantage in some cases) but sequence will complete on the first `false`.

Another approach is to use `Flux.concat` that sequentially subscribes to the first source then waiting for it to complete before subscribing to the next.

```
Flux.concat(condition1(), condition2(), condition3())
    .filter(res -> !res)
    .next() // emit first FALSE and stop
    .flatMap(__ -> otherAction()) // some condition FALSE
    .switchIfEmpty(action()); // all conditions TRUE
```

**UPDATE**

To achieve logical "or" condition with the above example (return `true` if any of the condition is `true`, and return `false` when all conditions are `false`)

```
Flux.concat(condition1(), condition2(), condition3())
    .filter(res -> res)
    .next() // emit first TRUE and stop
    .flatMap(__ -> action()) // some condition TRUE
    .switchIfEmpty(otherAction()); // all conditions FALSE
```

Comment: I used Flux.concat as suggested by @Alex, it worked by evaluating the conditions sequentially, just what I wanted to achieve. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: how would I achieve logical "or" condition with the above example, i.e. return true if any of the condition is true, and return false when all conditions are false. I am hoping that this can be achieved by tweaking the above Flux.concat  filter condition. kindly post the snippet for the same.

Comment: to process applying logical "or"  condition you can change filter and flip `flatMap` and `switchIfEmpty`. See updated answer for details